# Why does round raise on ndigits=None for integers but not for floats?

Tags: python, rounding, python-3.5

Why does `round()` behave different for int and float when `ndigits` is explicitly set to `None`?

Console test in Python 3.5.1:

```
>>> round(1, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>> round(1.0, None)
1
```

**Update:**

I reported this as a bug ([Issue #27936](https://bugs.python.org/issue27936)) which has been fixed and closed.
@PadraicCunningham and @CraigBurgler were correct.

The fix was included in the following final releases:

- [Python 3.5.3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/changelog.html) (2017-01-16)
- [Python 3.6.0](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/changelog.html) (2016-12-23)

Comment: I get the same `TypeError` in Python 3.4 for `round(1.0, None)`

Comment: I think because Integer don't need rounded.

Comment: @giaosudau:  You can use round on integers to round to nearest 10. `round(7, -1) => 10`

Comment: @giaosudau but `round(1, 1)` returns `1`

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L1018 https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4956 http://bugs.python.org/issue19933 the None check was implemented for the floatobject not the longobject, it is probably a bug if you look at it from a consistency perspective.

Comment: Probably related, from the source `builtin_round`, it refers to [*PEP 457*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/) as a comment in the [source: line 2014](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Python/bltinmodule.c) `builtin_round`: "AC: cannot convert yet, as needs PEP 457 group support in inspect or a semantic change to accept None for "ndigits""

Comment: Just curious, why would you try to use `None` for the number of digits? Is there a good use case for that?

Comment: @Mark Ransom I have a class representing a collection of numbers. When implementing `__round__` for that class `ndigits` was passed to `round()` for each of the individual numbers.

Comment: So, if this is indeed a bug, should I close my question?

Comment: @Jonatan, you can file a bug report https://bugs.python.org/ and update with the response in an answer.

Comment: @Jonatan no don't close the question, someone in the future might be wondering the same thing and this is a decent source of information. As far as implementing your own `__round__`, I tried it myself and found I had to supply my own default parameter, couldn't you just make the default `0`?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, 0 is a good idea. I was just surprised by the difference and wanted to know if it was by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code for `float_round` in `floatobjects.c` in `3.5`:

```
float_round(PyObject *v, PyObject *args)
    ... 
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "|O", &o_ndigits))
        return NULL;
    ...
    if (o_ndigits == NULL || o_ndigits == Py_None) {
        /* single-argument round or with None ndigits:
         * round to nearest integer */
        ...
```

The `|| o_ndigits == Py_None` bit catches an `ndigits=None` argument explicitly and discards it, treating the call to `round` as a single-argument call.

In `3.4`, this code looks like:

```
float_round(PyObject *v, PyObject *args)
    ... 
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "|O", &o_ndigits))
        return NULL;
    ...
    if (o_ndigits == NULL) {
            /* single-argument round: round to nearest integer */
    ...
```

there is no `|| o_ndigits == Py_None` test and hence an `ndgits=None` argument falls through and is treated like an `int`, thus causing a `TypeError` for `round(1.0, None)` in `3.4`.

There is no check for `o_ndigits == Py_None` in `long_round` in `longobject.c` in both `3.4` and `3.5`, thus raising a `TypeError` for `round(1, None)` in both `3.4` and `3.5`

```
                treat ndigits=None as      resolve
Version/Type    single-argument call    round(n, None) 
 ----------       ---------------        -----------
  3.4/float              No               TypeError
  3.4/long               No               TypeError
  3.5/float              Yes               round(n)
  3.5/long               No               TypeError
```

Comment: We already knew that this is in source code, OP wants to know that what's the underlying reason?

Comment: I have no clue why this answer is down-voted. This is precisely the *why*, described and shown with Python source code. Maybe Python shouldn't be written this way. If so, submit some change requests. But this is why `round()` behaves as it does.